# Change size in progressbar Android

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-progressbar

I have problem with size of progressbar in my ProgressDialog. How to change size of shape of my progressbar in ProgressDialog?. It should be thin line (1dip) but it is bigger than 1dip.

```
    pd = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.testing);
    pd.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.sr_progress_bar_message));
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    pd.setProgress(0);
    pd.show();
```

Style:

```
<style name="testing" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/color_primary</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle1">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Definiton:

pd.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_dialog));

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <size android:maxHeight="1dip" />
            <size android:minHeight="1dip" />
            <solid android:color="#808080"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <size android:maxHeight="1dip" />
                <size android:minHeight="1dip" />
                <solid android:color="#80ff0000"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <size android:maxHeight="1dip" />
                <size android:minHeight="1dip" />
                <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be specifying height for the `ProgressBar` and not the drawables?

Comment: How it make? Any example?

Comment: Maybe you could share your `Activity`/`Fragment` layout XML. I can show you with the help of it.

Comment: I found solution here: https://github.com/tir38/android-scaling-holo-progress-bar